# Instagram - API for filtering images in a date range

Tags: instagram

I want to get images uploaded to instagram in a date range? i have used this api http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/{id}/get_users_media_recent with all the combinations of parameter sequence but this doesn't work for me

Comment: we can get it by using the api https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/"+id+"/media/recent/min_timestamp=1388538061&max_timestamp=1390352461&access_token=mAccessToken

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot get `all` photos within a date range, you can get a particular user's photos with a date range, you can use `max_timestamp` and `min_timestamp` param in the API call to set date range, here is example:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/55431/media/recent/?max_timestamp=1367432682&min_timestamp=1364840682&client_id=CLIENT_ID
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply I have used access token instead of client id and it worked..

Comment: Am I not supposed to get all the posts in which created field will fall between the timestamps? But that doesn't seem to be the case. I'm using python-instagram, and trying to get user_liked_media objects beween a timerange (likes by the user in the last 7 days). But I get all the likes.

Comment: you will get 20 posts for each api call, use pagination to get next 20, u will have to make multipla calls until there is no pagination to get all between time range

Comment: I think nowdays min_timestamp and max_timestamp are no longer used by instagram... is thre any other option ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37020759/new-instagram-api-minimum-timestamp-disappears