# New Instagram API - Minimum timestamp disappears

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I am planning to use the /media/search endpoint in the Instagram API. For our purposes we would need to use MIN_TIMESTAMP to get publications written after a certain timestamp. However, I have noticed that this parameter is available in the deprecated API, and it is not available in the new API:

This is the endpoint in the deprecated API:
https://www.instagram.com/developer/deprecated/endpoints/media/#get_media_search

This is the endpoint in the new API:
https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/#get_media_search

As you can see, MIN_TIMESTAMP and MAX_TIMESTAMP disappear from the new documentation. However, I have performed a query with these parameters and they seem to work.

I have searched in [Instagram's developers blog](http://developers.instagram.com/) and I did not find any comment on this. 
Are these timestamp parameters disappearing in the future?

Answer (score 2):

The changes were rolled out today (1st June 2016) and you will see that now the `min_timestamp` is no longer taken in to account.